# Laravel validate() method returns index html page when false

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building my first laravel API and when I try to validate some mock form data using Postman with POST method, the application returns to me the HTML of the index page and status 200.

Here is my code

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
       'name' => 'required',
       'slug' => 'required',
       'price' => 'required'
    ]);

    return Product::create($request->all());
}
```

The application returns the object that was inserted in the database if the validation was successful (if the data was filled in), but returns a HTML file otherwise.

How can I change the way the method 'validate()' operates? I'm guessing it is just returning the user to the main page if the form data was not filled correctly

I am using Laravel 8

Comment: You need to return ajax response from your method for API requests. Also, when you will send request from postman, you will have to set the 'Accept' header to 'application/json' so that laravel recognizes the request and returns json response.

Comment: Solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must add `Accept: application/json` header to your Postman request, without this Laravel works as HTML.

But, in my opinion, all requests in an API must be forced to json response. For this, create `app/Http/Middleware/ForceJsonResponse.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ForceJsonResponse
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->headers->has('Accept')) {
            $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And add it to `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
  //other midlewares
  'json' => \App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class,
  //other midlewares
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
  'api' => [
    //other midlewares
    'json'
    //other midlewares
  ]
];
```

Answer (score 2):

I added Accept: application/json on postman and it worked
[image]